# How to reload Excel add-in for Desktop Version

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

We deployed Excel add-in project which was developed in Office Js in intranet. And manifest file uploaded in Office 365 admin center to reflect users. But it is working in Office online Excel version only. But in desktop version it is not getting refreshing and only showing old changes. Kindly help on this so that it can be upload with new changes to get reflect.

Comment: maybe try to clean the cache?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an add-in that you've previously sideloaded on Windows, Mac, or iOS by clearing the Office cache on your computer.

Additionally, if you make changes to your add-in's manifest (for example, update file names of icons or text of add-in commands), you should clear the Office cache and then re-sideload the add-in using updated manifest. Doing so will allow Office to render the add-in as it's described by the updated manifest.

To remove all sideloaded add-ins from Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, delete the contents of the folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\
```

To remove a sideloaded add-in from Outlook, use the steps outlined in [Sideload Outlook add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing) to find the add-in in the Custom add-ins section of the dialog box that lists your installed add-ins. Choose the ellipsis (...) for the add-in and then choose Remove to remove that specific add-in. If this add-in removal doesn't work, then delete the contents of the Wef folder as noted previously for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint.

Additionally, to clear the Office cache on Windows 10 when the add-in is running in Microsoft Edge, you can use the Microsoft Edge DevTools.

Read more about that in the [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) article.

Comment: @Eugene..Thanks for the update.. I hope the scenario you were trying to say for local running desktop excel appliation...But my requirement is for hosted application in desktop version only.... Manifest file uploaded using Office 365 admin center...

Comment: You can clear the cache from the web browser. Take a look at the article mentioned.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I am considering for both desktop and online excel version the same procedure for hosted application....