# Excel Add-In Requires Re-Installation to Update Files even when Cache is being Updated

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I currently have a few users setup to use my Add-In via sideloading from a network share. Today I made some changes to a JS file and tested with a user to see if their computer/Add-In updated and it did not.

First I tried just running the Add-In, that didn't work

Then I tried hitting "refresh" --> "Add" to "re-install" Add-In but that didn't work.

I had to completely wipe the users installation and start from scratch, that worked.

I figured this was something I could set/adjust in my nginx webserver so I set out to read/test but during my testing, I noted in `dev tools` that it was in fact getting `200` response and fetching updated files when they were updated on the nginx server.

This tells me that somehow Excel itself is caching the files outside of the browsers awareness or something and I'm at a loss what to do.

I will NOT change my file names for each deployment as that is no good for `git` and I prefer having the same file names.

Is there some other way I can ensure/push users Excel to fetch updated code?

Note: Users are 100% Windows Clients w/ Office 365

Update:

- I need a server side solution, I don't have the ability to run a script on end users computer to clear the cache/re-install with each update

Comment: This is really hindering uptake and it's hard to explain/convince users this is better then my previous distribution of the `xlam` which worked perfectly... Only dev's understand the reasoning.

Comment: Pure guess on my part, but [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150543/445425)?

Comment: MIcrosoft's recommendation for deploying Office Add-ins within an organization is to use [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/centralized-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide). You may also want to refer to [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) to get an overview of the Office Add-in deployment landscape,

Comment: @chrisneilsen that fix does work, but I can't run that on each terminal.

Comment: @joeschwa I don't currently have access to methods available under Centralized Deployment and IT has been "discussing" for weeks...months now. Issues like this are likely to cause project to never get off the ground. VBA may be ugly, but it worked perfectly at least.

Comment: I don't know anything about Excel Add-In, but to avoid cache or force update on JS included in web app, I use a token in the JS name, like myjs.js?v=15454, can you use the same trick?